# How to have a placeholder text and remove it when the first letter is inputted?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have been reading up on it to use textevent, but i am not even sure how to have the place holder.

What is the placeholder text? Another dynamic text field? 
For Example, on Facebook App, it says Email or phone on it, when i type 1 letter, the "Email or phone" disappear, but if i remove my input, the place holder appears again!

Somewhere to start me off would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I failed to google good link, but I think you can find useful Flex component by searching "Masked TextInput".

Comment: At the moment i am doing a "backup" option, just to set Email.text="Email" but then i have to delete it, and when it is deleted, it doesn't appear again if i dont input anything. On facebook's app, when you delete all text in the input the holder appears again. I am thinking if it is possible to have an an movieclip or sprite that act as the holder, then put an if statement that listen to the textinput event, if it is not null, holder=false? Is that possible if i do that?

Comment: As I understood, you described prompt text. In the flex it is implemented as "prompt" text when input is empty. Then remove it on focus in, and set it again on focus out and empty. Facebook way is also possible, but would require second textinput behind first one.

Comment: Ah ok, cos the problem for me is, i am doing the as3 code on Flash pro, so not very sure how to do that. But for now, i will give it a try for the prompt text.